# Reference to itself from inside a javascript generator object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a call to alert() with an iterator funcion and *yield*

See below a very basic snippet

```js
var globalFunction;

function* test () {

    /*
     test is a generator function. It will return an iterator function
     after this iterator function yields, I want it to continue when the 
     button2 is clicked. (Just as if the button2 is the button in an alert)
     Note than here the iterator function still doesn't exist, it will be 
     returned at the end of the generator function
    */ 
 var ele = document.getElementById("btn2");
 ele.onclick = function () {
  globalFunction.next();
  /* use some kind of 'this' here ? */
 };
 yield 1;

 console.log ("test2");
 yield 2;
}


function btn1 () {
 console.log ("btn1");

 var mytest = test();
 globalFunction = mytest;
 
 var res = mytest.next();
 console.log (res.value);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="btn1()">BTN1</button>
<button id="btn2">BTN2</button>
```

This snippet is working because I store the iterator in a global var and then asign it to the onclick when I need it.

But I don't like this way of working.

I would like to be able to access somehow the iterator function. At the point where there is the comment about using **this**.

I *know* that **this** won't work here !

But, isn't there any way to get a reference to the iterator function here ?

Another example to clarify :

```js
var globalFunction;
var span = document.getElementById("res");

function* test() {

  /*
   test is a generator function. It will return an iterator function
   after this iterator function yields, I want it to continue when the 
   button2 is clicked. (Just as if the button2 is the button in an alert)
   Note than here the iterator function still doesn't exist, it will be 
   returned at the end of the generator function
  */
  var ele = document.getElementById("btn2");
  ele.onclick = function() {
    globalFunction.next();
    /* use some kind of 'this' here ? */
  };

  var x;
  for (x = 1;; x++) {
    if (x % 7 == 0) {
      span.innerHTML = x + ' is divisible by 7. Hit btn2 to continue';
      yield;
    }
  }
}


function btn1() {
  console.log("btn1");

  var mytest = test();
  globalFunction = mytest;

  var res = mytest.next();
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="btn1()">BTN1</button>
<button id="btn2">BTN2</button>
<span id="res">Hit BTN1</span>
```

Comment: @brk function* defines the function as a generator. Then, yield is available in the iterator function.

Comment: A global variable is hard to avoid since 2 different onclick handlers need access to the same iterator instance. You may consider wrapping the entire code sample (including the variable) in a 'container' function, to limit the scope.

Comment: On a higher level; what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: For my understanding, why not assign `ele.onclick` in function `btn1` instead of in function `test`? That would eliminate the need for a global variable.

Comment: @charlietfl I have a large funtion that validates some data. At some point, I have a call to *alert('some message')* than will stop the process until the user accepts the message, and then will continue execution from this point. I am trying to use a click on button2 instead of the alert.

Comment: @RuudHelderman This could be a solution, but in my case btn2 is generated dynamically when needed. It still doesn't exist at the time. (I have posted a simplified case, just to show my problem). As a matter of fact, my current solution isn't using a global variable; but it is more complex than if I could somehow get the reference to the function as I ask.

Comment: could just use a promise that resolves in second button click

Comment: @charlietfl May be I could use a promise, but I can't see how. I have posted a second example. Can you use a promise in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

At last, I come up with a solution to have a reference to itself (sort of) inside the generator object

```
function runGenerator (gen) {

    function* wrapper () {
        var reflection = yield;

        yield* gen(reflection);
    }
    var genObj = wrapper();
    genObj.next();
    return genObj.next(genObj);
}
```